# CLI tool for XML patching on C#

Tags: open-source, c#, xml, mono

I found three opensource projects for XML diff - xmlunit.net, Diffplex and xmlspecificationcompare.

But only MSXmlDiffPatch allows to patch XML-files. But it is under EULA.

How to patch XML file from CLI, using opensource C# program?
Is there such program, which I didn't found? Or how to use programs mentioned above for patching?

RFC 5261 support will be good.

UPD: I found some library, which clams to be:
"tested with Appendix A
nearly complete, only 'Several Patches With Namespace Mangling' fails":

https://github.com/Bonuspunkt/XmlPatch

but it have no license.

Comment: Why do you care if it's in C#?

Comment: because my goal is to use MOSA on rspberry, which have no C++. Why do you insist on C++ ?